# Recover a users login events from a year ago

Tags: windows, login, active-directory

I have a client that is needing to get hold of a users login events from a year ago.

Unfortunately, Eventvwr only goes back to March 2017, we need to get back to October 2016.

The only way I know of finding a users login events it to check the Event Viewer Security Logs for event ID 4624.

Are there any other ways to get hold of this information?

========================================

Client is on Windows 7 Pro 64bit

Logging in as a Domain user via an SBS2011 domain

Comment: That would depend on the system. As for AD I'm not aware of an alternative method assuming no additional software or configuration has taken place.

Comment: I'l provide more info in question @Seth